# Moment JS Timezones - Is there a way to check if time is before specific time?

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I need some functionality in which I need to check if the local time on my machine is before 9am in a specific timezone, using momentjs, assuming all the imports work correctly, etc.

So for example, if my local time is 11am in New York, I would want to check if the time is before 9am in California.

This is the code I've been trying so far. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
if(moment().isBefore(moment(`${moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} 09:00:00`).tz('America/Los_Angeles'), 'second')) {
    console.log('it is before!');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that

```
moment(`${moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} 09:00:00`).tz('America/Los_Angeles')
```

does not represent *9:00 AM in California* (`'America/Los_Angeles'`) but is today at 9:00 AM in your local timezone converted to `'America/Los_Angeles'` timezone.

In your case you can use [`moment.tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) instead of the [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function.

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the `moment` constructor, but uses the last argument as a time zone identifier.

```js
// Compare current time with today at 9:00 am in Los Angeles
if(moment().isBefore(moment.tz('09:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles'), 'second')) {
    console.log('it is before!');
}

// Compare today at 11:00 am in New York with today at 9:00 am in Los Angeles
let mNewYork = moment.tz('11:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles');
let mCalifornia = moment.tz('09:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles')
if(mNewYork.isBefore(mCalifornia, 'second')) {
    console.log('it is before!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

I've simply used `'09:00:00'` string to get today at 9:00 am, because, [by default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/):

> You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! If I could expand it further, what if instead of the 11:00:00am time, what if it was just the local time at the time of render? Like `new Date()` kind of thing?

Comment: You can simply use [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) to get the current date and time. You can use `moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles')` to get the current date and time in Los Angeles, but note that `moment()` and `moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles')` are equivalent when used in [query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) functions like `isBefore`. Sorry, but I'm not sure I got the point in your comment.

Comment: hmmm yeah I thought I was using it correctly. Basically, in my app, I have it where data needs to be populated based on whether the local time of the machine rendering the results is before the date of the data's timezone date. So therefore if a user is happens to be in New York, it'd be like "alright, we're three hours ahead of someone in California, let's check to see what time it is there and make sure it's before 9am their time" kind of thing. The timezones could be all over the U.S.

Comment: actually, I think I misread what you had before. I think this line is what I'm looking for after all:

`// Compare current time with today at 9:00 am in Los Angeles
if(moment().isBefore(moment.tz('09:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles'), 'second')) {
    console.log('it is before!');
}`

Comment: I think that you are looking for the check of the first if of my snippet. In your question the issue is the way you are getting _9:00 am in California_, while `moment()` is fine to get current time in local time (New York or everywhere else)

Comment: You're right. I actually love you, it turns out. Thankyou so much for a comprehensive answer. I have struggled with times and timezones for many hours and you helped me. *virtual hug*